# Inserting PHP into jQuery css()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, wordpress

I'm working on a WordPress theme and I have come across a little block.  I have a small app within the theme that highlights a person's name when you click on it:

jQuery

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".testimonial-person").click(function() {
            $(".testimonial-person").css( "background", "none");
            var tID = this.id;
            $("#" + tID).css( "background", "url('images/halftone.png') #DDD");
            $(".testimonial-text").fadeOut(100);
            $("#box-" + tID).delay(102).fadeIn(100);
        });
    </script>
```

The issue is that the `css()` line that shows a background image, that background image is actually a dynamic value - something that would look like this:

```
$("#" + tID).css( "background", "url('<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>/images/halftone.png' #DDD");
```

See how the quote marks contradict each other?  Does anyone know a way around this, OR a better way to call the image in WordPress?

Comment: The single quotes should not affect the PHP. The problem is probably that you are not `echo`ing it.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen `bloginfo()` does the echo itself. to get the value you need to use `get_bloginfo()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quotes don't matter at all in this particular case, as the quotes you use between `<?php` and `?>` are interpreted by php and as such never reach the browser, where the javascript will be interpreted. Actually, the problem is that you forgot a closing `)`. Your ouput will now be:

```
$("#" + tID).css( "background", "url('http://url.com/images/halftone.png' #DDD");
```

And correct would be:

```
$("#" + tID).css( "background", "url('http://url.com/images/halftone.png') #DDD");
```

Take attention to the second closing parenthesis after the `...halftone.png'`

So your php code would look like this:

```
$("#" + tID).css( "background", "url('<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url'); ?>/images/halftone.png') #DDD");
```